# Webservice stops working until I republish source files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

A little background on my application.

Using ASP.NET 4.0 / C# Web Forms for a web page that is pretty JavaScript heavy. I also utilize ASP.NET Web Services that return/update to a SQL Server via LINQ.

I started having an issue where certain web service will start failing randomly (won't return any data). The only way I have been able to fix it is by taking the source files and overwriting the current files. I literally have a zip file of the source files, and I simply extract the exact same files over the current ones, and immediately after the webpage starts working again.

At this point I'm a little lost as to what could be causing this.

Comment: Disting new files will cause IIS to reload the website, so that's why you are seeing it working again. As for finding the problem, check the event log, check for excessive cpu or memory usage (ie, possible infinite loops). Or trace the queries on the server to see if it is stuck asking for the same query over and over.

Comment: In regards to IIS reloading. When I manually restart the website without replacing the source files, it does not work.